# Warp in glueup of endgrain cutting board?

Tags: hand-planing, end-grain, cutting-board

Hey guys so I started my first real big woodworking project in a while, may have underestimated the intensity and precision of it just a bit so I'm debating on how best to save it. My first glueup of an endgrain cutting board had a little warp in it and me being as inexperienced as I am I figured ah heck just plane it even. Now though I'm realizing I'm losing quite a bit of the board and the final dimensions look sadder and sadder every day. My question is if i saw it into strips and then glue it together maybe pack the void with saw dust would that work, or is my only option to plane it until even with the low point?

[image: my board as it stands now]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. For a butcher block I wouldn't pack any vids with sawdust and glue (if for no other reason that it'll look pretty awful). It's hard to know how best to proceed as that warp is pretty severe. Did this happen during the glue-up or were you aware you had warp in the material before you started? If you can't/don't want to lose any more thickness then the usual recommendation is the strips need to come apart, but you lose material that way too (even more if you're not able to rip it using a table saw). It is possible that flattening what you have is the best way to go.

Comment: So, taking every mistake/disaster as a learning opportunity do you know what you'd do differently next time? Is this maple and cherry? If either one had some warp in it before you began it would actually have been best to either A) cut it into shorter strips (always lessens the curvature) and move ahead with those, even though it means having to do more glue-ups or B) not use the material at all (for this).

Comment: Definitely aware of what I would do differently, and yes maple and cherry. It didn't look quite as severe when I was doing the gluing but I think I really underestimated how much would come off. I don't have a table saw handy but do have an edge guard sitting around for a handheld so I suppose ripping it may be my best choice fortunately I do have some maple left I can do into a couple of strips. I think to get it flat it would take at least another 1/10th

Comment: or maybe more of an inch and my boards are already ending up a little underspeced sitting at 9/10ths of my original goal of 1 right now which surprisingly cuts quite a bit into end dimensions

Comment: Is the loss of final dimension from taking the current glue-up down to flat enough of an issue to compensate for the greater effort taking this apart and re-glueing? It's also trying to figure how much you'll lose to the saw kerf and subsequent planing/sanding, I think it could be more unfortunately.

Comment: BTW, how are you planing this down? If you're not using a jack or fore plane, or any other plane set up to remove lots of material, *and* traversing I would strongly recommend it.